# How to do a POST web api call with groovy code?

Tags: groovy

I have some POST method url, 2 headers to pass and a big body in Json format, that I need to call through the Groovy code. But I am not sure on points like how to pass headers and big Json object in Groovy code for API call. Please help me on thease points.  I am writin this code in visual code.

```
Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', module='http-builder', version='0.7.1' )
import groovyx.net.http.*
import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.*
import static groovyx.net.http.Method.*

def post = new URL("https://xyxz/api/testRequest/generic").openConnection();
def message = '{
  "test": "test",
  "test1": "test1\n\t",
  "test2": {
    "test3": "test3",
    "test4": "test4"
  }'

post.setRequestMethod("POST")
post.setDoOutput(true)
post.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json")
post.setHeader("id","sadasdas1212134");
post.setHeader("id2","sdsd34sdsfdfdfdf");
post.getOutputStream().write(message.getBytes("UTF-8"));
def postRC = post.getResponseCode();
println(postRC);
if(postRC.equals(200)) {
    println(post.getInputStream().getText());
}
```

Comment: Does this code work?  If not: please add the errors you get

Comment: Yes, Problem I am facing is how to pass the big json object in api call?

Comment: @cfrick My object is bigger than that I mentioned in the question.

Comment: If you have errors, please add them to the question.  Also add the code, you are actually having the problem with (or even better distill it down).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straight from the [ref-doc](https://http-builder-ng.github.io/http-builder-ng/asciidoc/html5/)

```
import groovyx.net.http.HttpBuilder

def body = [
    "test": "test",
    "test1": "test1\n\t",
    "test2": [
      "test3": "test3",
      "test4": "test4"
    ]
]

def result = HttpBuilder.configure {
    request.uri = 'https://xyxz/api/testRequest/generic'
    request.headers.id = 'sadasdas1212134'
    request.headers.id2 = 'sdsd34sdsfdfdfdf'
    request.contentType = 'application/json'
    request.body = body
}.post()

println result
```

Comment: it's giving me error
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: HttpBuilder for class: test3
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: HttpBuilder for class: test3

Comment: you must import the HttpBuilder class and maybe use the `@Grab('io.github.http-builder-ng:http-builder-ng-CLIENT:1.0.4')` on top

Comment: When i include `@Grab('io.github.http-builder-ng:http-builder-ng-CLIENT:1.0.4')
import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder` I am getting error 
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
General error during conversion: Error grabbing Grapes -- [unresolved dependency: io.github.http-builder-ng#http-builder-ng-CLIENT;1.0.4: not found]

Comment: maybe doc is not up to date, try this dependency https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.http-builder-ng/http-builder-ng-core/1.0.4

Comment: it says `org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder
 @ line 2, column 1.
   @Grab('io.github.http-builder-ng:http-builder-ng-core:1.0.4')
   ^`

Comment: you must set up your environment properly

Comment: Now I am getting 400 error, not sure if i am able to send correct complex json object to the server, can you please help me on it, how to send the complex json object to the server.

Comment: I am using post.getOutputStream().write(jsobBody.getBytes("UTF-8"));

Comment: I am getting error , groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.LinkedHashMap.getBytes() is applicable for argument types: (String) values: [UTF-8]